# MUI V5 use Emotion or CSS Modules

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, emotion

I'm working on creating a shared library in React and I'm pretty new to React language and a little confused about what CSS pattern should i use.

Looking at MUI site, on V5 they suggest to use Emotion to customize their components (if SX is not enough) but reading around the web, it looks like CSS modules is a much better solution

Correct me if I'm wrong, but Emotion is a CSS in JS library so it has the following advantages / disadvantages:

**Emotion**

**Pros**:

- We can style dynamically using JS based on props and code looks cleaner
- Code looks cleaner since with use the styled component name `<CustomButton></CustomButton>` and don't need to add `className=`.

**Cons**

- Delayed rendering since we need to parse from JS to CSS
- No caching
- No CSS preprocessor support (SCSS)
- Bigger bundle size then CSS modules
- Server-side rendering problems
- Can get deprecated like MUI V4 did to MakeStyles and moved to Emotion

**CSS Modules**

**Pros**

- More organized since we create a CSS for each component and don’t need the CSS to be in the same file.
- Caching works.
- We can add SCSS.
- If we change framework for example from React to Vue or Angular – easier

**Cons**

- Setting global style needs to have a :global in the beginning of the CSS class (removes the unique id https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/ )
- No JS in CSS (dynamic styling)
- Need to import the CSS each time at the top of the file.
- Working with typescript, you need to generate interfaces automatically or manually.

Am I missing any other important Pros / Cons I should take into consideration?